# correct way to use this function

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

i saw this function 'is_post' at this website:

http://www.kylenoland.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-securing-codeigniter-2-x-with-ben-edmunds-ion-auth/

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function is_post()
    {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
}
```

May i know the correct way to use this function and how? thanks.
regards,
zs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the advantages of using your own parent controller is that the common checks can be checked at central position. so when you are creating/defining a controller, you can inherit from your own controller, like below to use parent class methods:

```
class User_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->is_post()){
            //login check and redirect if successfull.
        }
        $this->load->view("login");
    }
}
```